# Circular Import with app models

Tags: python, django

I have an app in two different models, The error is 'cannot import name sku', which i believe is because of a circular import. How can I still reference this app.model without referencing the model import the way I am currently.

Model PurchaseOrderDetail
App Purchase_order

```
from product.models import InventoryTransaction


class PurchaseOrderDetail(AuditMixin, models.Model):
    purchase_order = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, 
    on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    sku = models.ForeignKey(Sku, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    qty_received = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    reason_code = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)

    def _get_sku_code(self):
        return self.sku.sku_code

    def _set_sku_code(self, value):
        tenant = self.purchase_order.tenant
        sku = Sku.objects.get(tenant=tenant, sku_code=value)
        self.sku = sku

    sku_code = property(_get_sku_code, _set_sku_code)

    def calc_received(self):
        # calculate sum of qty_received from inventory_transactions
        sum_quantity = InventoryTransaction.objects.filter(
            sku=self.sku,
            po_number=self.purchase_order,
            transaction_type='100'
        ).aggregate(
            quantity_sum=Sum(F('quantity'))
        )
        return sum_quantity
```

Model Inventorytransaction
app Product

```
from purchase_order.models import PurchaseOrderDetail


class InventoryTransaction(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant)
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inventory_transaction = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrderInventoryTransaction)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        # update the PO detail with the qty_received
        obj = PurchaseOrderDetail.objects.get(
            purchase_order=self.po_number,
            sku=self.inventory_transaction.sku
        )
        obj.qty_received = obj.calc_received()
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want this problem to appear, simply import your PurchaseOrderDetails inside your `def save` function.

`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from purchase_order.models import PurchaseOrderDetail
    ...`

Comment: I actually just tried that right before reading this. Thank you

Comment: Another option is to use models signals (`post_save()` would be an obvious candidate) to decouple InventoryTransaction from PurchaseOrderDetail.